# Error messages are not displayed in showForm() while using the Validator interface

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm validating a form using the `Validator` interface with Spring MVC 3.0.2 using `SimpleFormController`. The following is the controller class which extends `SimpleFormController`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
final public class Temp extends SimpleFormController
{        
    public Temp()
    {
        setCommandClass(ValidationForm.class);
        setCommandName("validationForm");
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        ValidationBean validationBean=(ValidationBean) command;
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", validationBean);
        if(errors.hasErrors())
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("name = "+validationBean.getUserName());
        }
        return mv;
    }        

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", errors.getTarget());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

There is no question about form-validation. It works fine. The only question here is that when I use the `showForm(...){...}` method as shown above, the error messages are not displayed because this method calls when the JSP page is loaded and also, after the `onSubmit()` method completes (In case, the page is submitted by clicking the submit button on the JSP page).

When the page is submitted by clicking the submit button, the command object which is `errors.getTarget()` (or `getCommand(request)`) in the `showForm()` method (which is called after the `onSubmit()` method) contains no error messages to be displayed on the page. The command object (or domain object) is different from the command object in the `onSubmit()` method. (and therefore, when the `showForm()` method is commented out, it displays error messages)

I need to use the `showForm()` method to display a list of data from the database when the page is either submitted or loaded.

Of course, the `referenceData()` method as shown below does the trick.

```
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request, Object command, Errors errors) throws Exception
{    
    Map map=new HashMap();
    return map;
}
```

but I want to stick at the `showForm()` method. Is there a fair way to display error messages while using the `showForm()` method while validating a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client-side, you can use the contents of error object to display errors, along with the form. Note that onSubmit() and showForm() are deprecated in spring 3.0.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
final public class Temp extends SimpleFormController 
{         
    public Temp() 
    { 
        setCommandClass(ValidationForm.class); 
        setCommandName("validationForm"); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception 
    { 
        ValidationBean validationBean=(ValidationBean) command; 
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", validationBean); 
        if(errors.hasErrors()) 
        { 
            System.out.println("error"); 
            errors.reject("error.server.error");
            return showForm(request, response, errors);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            System.out.println("name = "+validationBean.getUserName()); 
        } 
        return mv; 
    }         

    @Override 
    protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception 
    { 
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", errors.getTarget()); 
        return mv; 
    } 
}
```

**Sample JSP code:**

For example in jsp if you need to display error messages you can use like:

```
<span class="error">${error}</span>
```

error is the attribute which we need to set in spring.

Comment: Thank a lot man for your effort. Sorry to say, I tried it but didn't work directly. I don't know how to use the `error` object on the client-side. I'm currently using the `referenceData(){}` method as mentioned in the question instead of using the `showForm()` method though I insisted upon the `showForm` method. So, I would be very grateful to you, if you were to explain me how I can use the `error` object to display error messages on the client-side. I however have nothing to lose accepting your answer (as it seems to be correct to me). Thanks again.